# Delete remote files using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, delete-file, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

How do I delete all files in a source folder (located on On-premise file system). I would need help with a .NET custom activity or any Out-of-the-box solutions in Azure Data Factory. 


PS: I did find a delete custom activity but it's more towards Blob storage. 

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is NO support for a custom activity on Data Management Gateway. Data Management Gateway only supports copy activity and Stored Procedure activity as of today (02/22/2017).

Work Around: As I do not have a delete facility for on-premise files, I am planning to have source files in folder structures of yyyy-mm-dd. So, every date folder (Ex: 2017-02-22 folder) will contain all the related files. I will now configure my Azure Data Factory job to pull data based on date. 

Example: The ADF job on Feb 22nd will search for 2017-02-22 folder. In the next run my ADF job will search for 2017-02-23 folder. This way I don't need to delete the processed files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a normal way to do it. You will have to create Azure Functions App that will accept POST with your FTP/SFTP settings (in case you use one) and file name to remove. Therefore you parse request content to JSON, extract settings and use SSH.NET library to remove desired file. In case you have just a file share, you do not even need to bother with SSH.
Later on in Data Factory you add a Web Activity with dynamic content in Body section constructing the JSON request in the form I've mentioned above. For URL you specify published Azure Function Url + `?code=<your function key>`
We actually ended up creating the whole bunch of Azure Functions that serve as custom activities for our DF pipelines.

Comment: It can be done even simplier with logic apps that would be executing ADF pipeline. And you can add competency actions before and after ADF execution